# Creating a simple Google App using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

We are working to integrate one of our client's existing accounting system into Google App. Eventually we need to list it on Google App Marketplace.

Here is what we have already done:

- Downloaded the sample .NET app available from Google - [this one](http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_dotnet.html)
- Created a vendor profile on the Google Apps Marketplace
- Listed our test application on the Google Apps Marketplace

So far we have ONLY been able to authenticate the user using DotNetOpenAuth.

We are struggling with following issues:

- Unable to access the Calendar Data API and display the next appointment. We are getting 401 Unauthorized when querying the Calendar Data API.
- To access the Calendar Data API we need to have a ConsumerKey & a ConsumerSecret - which is made available ONLY after you submit your application for Approval.
- We submitted the app for approval to get a ConsumerKey & a ConsumerSecret although its just a pilot app that we are building first. We don't want that app to be published as of now but we could not find a way to keep that listing private and available ONLY for dev & testing purpose as of now.
- We have placed the ConsumerKey & ConsumerSecret in the sample marketplace app but even now we get a 401 Unauthorized access while quering the Calendar Data API.

We have already spent 2-3 days trying to find proper documentation for this and get it to work but in vain. Any help / guidance to get it to work and also keep the listing private in dev mode until we are ready, would be really appreciated.

[Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11374665/helloworld_dotnet.rar) is the modified 2 page source code i am trying to run.

Comment: You should be able to authenticate with your gmail details to get calendar information.

Comment: i have authenticated every thing but when i try to access the calendar information through the calendar API, i always get 401.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to authenticate?

Comment: i have update the post above to include a link to code as well.

Answer (score 4):

There are some key misconceptions in your post.

1. Your keys are already available to you.  Open Marketplace, click on "My Vendor Profile" top right, and look right under the listing, below the stars: View OAuth Consumer Key link is there.  If it isn't, you did not mark your app as an installable one.  To fix that, create a new app entry, and make sure you provide a valid manifest.
2. To test your new app, BEFORE you submit your app for approval, open the Marketplace page for it and click the Add it now button.  You will be offered a field to enter the Google Apps domain name to test with.

**Only domains you add your app to will be accessible with the marketplace key.**

Chances are if you sort these two things out things will start working :)

Comment: 1. We have the consumerKey & ConsumerSecret already, i just wanted to understand the mechanics of the same.

Comment: 2. I have done "Add it now" as a domain administrator and entered the domain name. I even see the app link in the global navigation bar but when i try to access it i get 401 Unauthorized.